# Two scroll bars inside the browser

Tags: html, website-design, blogger

My is actually a blogger.com blog , I use custom url on it and also use a custom theme. I do minor edits and insert certain html for features like "addthis" "disqus for comments" and etc..
My blog now show me two scroll bars. one is active the other acts like a window. The attached screenshot is here, Kindly help me resolving this issue. you can see it in the right side of the window.
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

> My blog now show me two scroll bars

The outer, inactive, scrollbar is on the `body`. You have an inner `div` element (`<div class="sitebwrap">`) that contains all your content which also has a scrollbar because it appears to be inheriting `overflow: auto` from the `body` (parent element). You don't need `overflow:auto` on both.

However, this appears to be getting added by JavaScript - which is adding inline styles to the `body` element.

Comment: I have solved the issue it was happening because of pop up i used in my page for subscription. once i remove that particular script the problem went away. thanks for your support.